# How to shift binary number to the left

Tags: perl, binary, shift

simple thing, how to print a binary number and shift it to the left?

```
$num = 0b00000010001;
for(0..6){
    print sprintf ("%b",$num), "\n";
    $num<<1;
}
```

problem of this code: it doesn't print the 0's before 1! the resoult of print is just "10001", and it doesn't shift the number.

the final output should be:

```
00000010001
00000100010
00001000100
00010001000
00100010000
01000100000
10001000000
```

Comment: `print sprintf` is better written `printf`.

Comment: nit: You're doing a left shift, not a right shift.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot thx, didnt even notice

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just tell the formatter that you need to print exactly N (11) digits in any case, and that `0` should be used as a padding symbol:

```
my $num = 0b00000010001;
for (0..6) {
    printf("%011b\n", $num);
    $num <<= 1;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/129639).

Two sidenotes here

- First, it's obviously redundant to do `print sprintf`: `printf` will replace it quite well.
- Second, in the original code you forgot to assign the result of shifting back to `$num`. Had you started your script with the `use warnings` pragma (like in my demo), you'd have been notified about it with `Useless use of left bitshift (<<) in void context...`

Comment: Good answer. You could also mention that `use warnings` would have given information about the shifting mistake: `Useless use of left bitshift (<<) in void context`

Comment: Ah, yes. I added them to demo script automatically, but forgot to mention that in the answer. ) Thanks.